# Change user's voice channel with POST message

Tags: node.js, express, discord, discord.js

I'm making a Discord bot for a specific application that requires changing the user's voice channel when the bot receives a POST call, but I'm struggling to properly call the Discord part.
Right now I can do this with a command using this code

```
bot.on("message", async (message) => {
  let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
  let command = messageArray[0];
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.channel.type === "dm") return;
  if (!command.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  if (command === `${prefix}tochannel`) {
    let channelID = messageArray[1];
    if (!channelID) return message.channel.send("Please specify the channel ID!");
    message.member.voice.setChannel(channelID);
  }
});
```

I also have a little code in Express to call a form with two text fields just for testing

```
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

  app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
  });

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  var toChannel = Number(req.body.channelID);
  var userID = Number(req.body.userID);
  console.log(channelID);
  console.log(userID);
  res.send("Channel ID: " + channelID + "  >>  " + "User ID: " + userID);
});
```

My big nightmare is: how do I get these two universes to talk to each other?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your `bot` variable to find the specific guild you are working in, then find the specific member you want to change the voice channel of, and then do so. Here's an example in your express POST handler:

```
app.post("/", async function (req, res) {
  const toChannel = req.body.channelID
  const userID = req.body.userID
  console.log(channelID);
  console.log(userID);

  //Use your client object, in your case saved to the variable "bot"
  try {
        let guild = bot.channels.cache.get(toChannel).guild;
        let member = await guild.members.fetch(userID);
        member.voice.setChannel(toChannel);

        res.send(`Channel ID: ${channelID} >> User ID:  ${userID}`);
  } catch(e) {
        res.send(`An error occurred: ${err.stack}`);
  }
});
```

Note that this is an untested example, and I do not know if it works exactly as is. You may need to tweak this a bit to get it working, and you should check to make sure the guild and member are found before going ahead and attempting to change the member's channel. But I hope it gives you a general idea of how you would go about this, that you can use your `bot` variable to do so.

Relevant resources:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client